# Populate Dropdown in Partial View with Jquery AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I'm new to jquery with JSON and am trying to populate my dropdown with the results I get back. I basically have a button that will open a partial view in one ajax call and then get the dropdown data back through another ajax call.

Here is my button-

```
<button type="button" id="createIssueBtn" class="btn btn-lg btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#PopUpDiv">I need to create an issue</button><br/>
<div id="PopUpDiv"></div>
```

Here is the javascript on the page-

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#createIssueBtn').bind("click", function () {
            $.ajax({

                url: '@Url.Action("OpenPopUp", "Issues")',
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function (html) {
                    $('#PopUpDiv').html(html);
                }
            }
        )
            $.ajax({

                dataType: "json",
                url: '@Url.Action("GetIssueTypes", "Issues")',
                success: function (data) {

                    $.each(data.IssueTypes, function (index, item) {

                        $("#selectIssueType").append(
                            $("<option></option>")
                                .text(item.IssueType)
                                .val(item.IssueID)
                            )
                    })
                }
            })
        })

    })
</script>
```

And this is the partial view-

```
<div id="AddIssues"><br/>


<div >
<select id="selectIssueType">
    <option value="0">Select Issue Type...</option>
</select>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div>Enter the details of the issue (be specific):</div>
    <div><input type="text" id="IssueDetails" /></div>
    <br/>
    <p>Location of Issue:</p>
    <div><input type="text" id="IssueLocation" /></div>
    <div>&nbsp;<br/></div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to populate the select. I get the data back but the binding is what is throwing me off.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Here is my IssueTypes object-

```
public class IssueTypes
    {
        public int IssueID { get; set; }

        public string IssueType { get; set; }
    }
```

**EDIT**

Here is my GetIssueTypes function in the Issues controller-

```
 public ActionResult GetIssueTypes()
        {
            List<IssueTypes> issuesList = new List<IssueTypes>();

            issuesList = issueService.GetAllIssueTypes().data.Select(w => new IssueTypes()
            {
                IssueID = w.IssueID,
                IssueType = w.IssueType
           }).ToList();

            return Json(issuesList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: Why not just use `$('#createIssueBtn').click(function() {...});`

Comment: You have not explained what is not working in your question!. But you have multiple issues with your code, not the least being that ajax is async and 2nd ajax call may be executed before you first ajax call as completed, meaning your adding `<option>` elements to `<select>` which does not even exist yet.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I'm not able to bind the data that is coming back through my Ajax call.

Comment: Read my comment again :) - you cannot add elements to an element which does not even exist yet - you need to make the 2nd ajax call in the success callback of the first ajax call. That will solve the immediate issue, but you really need to go to the MVC site and work through the tutorials to learn the basics including how to generate a view and bind to a model using the `HtmlHelper` methods

Comment: @StephenMuecke alright that makes sense. I put the second call within the success but that didn't do anything.  And yeah I'm pretty new to MVC haha for now just trying to learn binding data with Ajax

Comment: Then what errors are you getting in the browser console? You have not even shown your `GetIssueTypes()` method! And why are you degrading performance by making a 2nd ajax call anyway, instead of populating the options in the partial

Comment: @StephenMuecke that's the thing im not getting any error.. when i debug i see the data coming back. its the binding that is throwing me off. i was thinking of maybe trying to use angular but im not too familiar with it either. and i've added in my GetIssueTypes() method. All i need is for it to populate the dropdown select. i also tried adding in the select on the same page to see if having the select exist would append the options but that didnt do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Angular JS. My select ->

```
<div ng-controller="IssueTypes">
                <select id="issueTypeSelect" ng-model="issueTypeModel">
                    <option ng-repeat="issue in issueTypes" value="{{issue.IssueID}}">{{issue.IssueType}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
```

My Angular code-

```
 var app = angular.module('Cartegraph', []);
    app.controller('IssueTypes', function IssueTypesController($scope, $http) {

        var url = '@Url.Action("GetIssueTypes", "Issues")';
        $http.get(url).then(function (response) {

            var _data = angular.fromJson(response);
            $scope.issueTypes = _data.data;
        })
    })
```